# What is the best algorithm for speech to text with a known dictionary

Tags: android, ios, speech-to-text

I have seen lot of questions with this topic and read alot of articles but still cant find the best sloution for what I am looking for.
I want to build an app (Android/IOS/...whatever) which has this feature:
when the user write down a text (using killboard), the app will can recognize speech to text on what he wrote with 99.9% performance, I dont mind if he would have to record his voise first to make performance better... I want it to be "live" like Google Servies unlike Seri that writes the texts only after you finish talking.
I have found this site:
http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net
and I wish to start working with it but before start I wanted to make sure it is the best way.
can anyone give some advises?
thanks
*edit: I dont care to build a new field for a new launguage if needed (its not in english).

Comment: You need to realize that text-to-speech services like siri and google now upload a recording of your voice to a server, which computes the voice and returns the data. A phone is going to provide a poor experience on its own, it just isn't powerful enough.

Comment: text-to-speech / speech-to-text / both?
I am intersted in speech to text. dont care to use internet. not only on the phone.. it can be on pc too. I want the best performance.

Answer (score 0):

I mean like, if you do some research you'll see that 99% accuracy in speech-to-text is only a very recent thing, and an example is Nuance's [Dragon](http://www.nuance.com/dragon/index.htm).

High accuracy speech-to-text can cost around $600 for a license. It's not an easy thing to create. You have to pay for high accuracy TTS libraries.

For what you're doing though, a really good service I have used is [Wit.ai](https://wit.ai/). It's very accurate, and its getting faster every week.

Comment: thank you.
why the two answers or about text-to-speech lol
I am intersted in speech-to-text.. or its the same performance?
I dont care to pay 600$ if it gives me great performance. but I want to build a new field for a new launguage... can I do it with Wit.ai?
whanks agian

Comment: Wit.ai is speech-to-text and text-to-speech.

Dragon is also speech-to-text, I just wrote it down wrong. Edited.

Comment: Also, the accuracy is incredible on Nuance. I have not used their mobile sdk however. It is [here](http://dragonmobile.nuancemobiledeveloper.com/public/index.php?task=home)

Comment: aa ok thank you. so about this site... can I build a new field with it? I need it not in english.. I need to make it for a special launguage

Comment: Nuance can support these languages [here](http://www.nuance.com/for-business/by-solution/customer-service-solutions/solutions-services/inbound-solutions/self-service-automation/recognizer/recognizer-languages/index.htm). Wit.ai I believe is 'natural' language so it should work with other languages. It is free to try, so try it out.

Comment: well excuseme for my qustions, but I still confused. in the link you give I see about 86 launguages, and I can find the laungauge I want, but, I want to make some edit on it, I will describe in english:
lets say, the letter "e" , I want to make it "eeee" means more longer... and some more edits...
is this site just provide somthing ready for use or I can edit the algorithem??
sorry.. I am new to this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/77648/discussion-between-user3036061-and-vee).

Answer (score 0):

Another possibility for you might be the AT&T speech engine (Watson) found here: http://developer.att.com/
They offer 1 million API calls per month for a fee(low) and allow you to customize the "library" you use to recognize speech. It might be what you are looking for given your latest statements. You can try it for free though it is throttled until you pay.